# PVlib: modelchain.run_model_from_poa() not found after installation?

Tags: pvlib

I am trying to model an Agri-PV system (90° tilt and 90/270° azimuth with bifacial panels) and running into the following problem: I don't seem to have the .run_model_from_poa() function, perhaps the installation was incomplete. This is on a company laptop, deinstalling and reinstalling would require IT support, unfortunately. On my private machine, regular installation ("conda install -c pvlib pvlib") also does not leave me with the desired poa function.

How do I get the .run_model_from_poa() function?

Any help is appreciated!

Kind regards,
Gregor

Installation on company and private machine using the anaconda prompt command "conda install -c pvlib pvlib". In both cases I only have the .run_model() function, but not .run_model_from_poa()

Comment: `run_model_from_poa` was added in v0.8.0 (see the [what's new](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew.html#id25) page).  What pvlib version do you have installed?  `conda list pvlib`

Comment: that might be it, thanks! My version is 0.7.2. How do I upgrade to the newest version? Best, Gregor

Comment: Installing specific versions is done with e.g. `conda install -c pvlib pvlib=0.9.3` (or `pip install pvlib==0.9.3`), but it sounds like you might need help from your IT department for that.

Comment: that is true but now I can tell them what to enter specifically thanks to you!